# Which ReSharper command causes the Context Action List to pop up?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, keyboard, resharper, shortcut

I've turned off ReSharper intellisense but still want a keyboard shortcut for opening the context action list (the one that pops up on the left when you point at a piece of code). Unfortunately, I cannot find the ReSharper command for this to bind it to a keyboard key. Can you help?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're after <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is the refactor this shortcut.

VisualStudio Command Name => **Resharper_QuickFix**

Comment: I mean the command name, not the shortcut keys. Alt+Enter does nothing on my machine, Ctrl+Shift+R is 'record temporary macro'.

Comment: Looking through the keyboard shortcut macro (http://xona.com/2005/08/02.html) output the command seems to be called "ReSharper_QuickFix".

You could also reset your keyboard shortcuts I guess (Resharper->Options->General). Unless you have a good reason to do otherwise pick Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

In Resharper 9 this command is called **Alt_Enter**. In case someone would like to map it to another shortcut

Comment: Strange they withdrew the "ReSharper" prefix from the command name, but sure enough this is it.